# Does Azure Logic app support OAuth 1.0 Protocol with header authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to read data by consuming REST API provided by an external data provider. This API supports only OAuth 1.0 authentication. I am using Azure logic app HTTP trigger to call this API. I would like to know if Does Azure Logic app support OAuth 1.0 Protocol with header authentication.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#authentication) url and it looks like it is not supported however this article seems old. Can someone suggest any pointers?